# how to write down dynamical state space models with deterministic variables in PyMC?

Tags: machine-learning, python, markov-process, hidden-markov-model, pymc

is it possible to write down this simple dynamical system in pymc?

$R_0 \sim Normal(\mu_r, \sigma_r)$

$Z_0 \sim Normal(\mu_z, \sigma_z)$

$R_t \sim Normal(R_{t-1}, \sigma_r)$

$Z_t = Z_{t-1} + R_{t-1}Z_{t-1}$

here there is a rate $R_t$ evolving through time, and the rate $R_t$ controls the change of the system output $Z_t$. $Z_t$'s value is a deterministic function of $R_{t-1}$ (which is stochastic) and $Z_{t-1}$.

the code for this is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

n = 20
data = [1]*n
# true r
r_val = -0.5
for t in range(1, n):
    data[t] = data[t-1] + (r_val*data[t-1])
mu = 1
r_sd = 0.001
z_sd = 0.01
vars = {}
vars["z0"] = pymc.Normal("z0", mu=1, tau=1/z_sd)
vars["r0"] = pymc.Normal("r0", mu=1, tau=1/r_sd)
for t in range(1, n):
    prev_r = vars["r%d" %(t-1)]
    prev_z = vars["z%d" %(t-1)]
    vars["r%d" %(t)]=pymc.Normal("r%d" %(t), mu=prev_r, tau=1/r_sd)
    # z(t) = z(t-1) + z(t-1)*r(t-1)
    # can this be written without Normal, as Deterministic?
    vars["z%d" %(t)]=pymc.Normal("z%d" %(t), mu=prev_z + prev_r*prev_z, tau=1/z_sd,
                                 observed=True, value=data[t])
model = pymc.Model(vars.values())
m = pymc.MCMC(model)
m.sample(iter=2000)
# plot results
plt.figure()
mean_r = []
for i in range(n):
    mean_r.append(np.mean(m.trace("r%d" %(i))[:]))
plt.plot(range(n), mean_r, label="pymc")
plt.plot(range(n), [r_val] * n, label="true")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

*my question is:* what is wrong with this way of writing the model? it doesn't update based on observations and gives the prior on $R_t$.

i tried to use `pymc.Lambda()` to write down $Z_t$ but I get the same results.